# Is it safe to change the OAuth Domain?

Tags: support, oauth2

I'm about to develop a small application that will use the Stack Exchange API. I understand that I have to provide an OAuth Domain when I register the application with Stack Exchange. Right now, I am planning to host the application under a subdomain of my personal domain. If the application gets popular, I may consider buying a new domain name for it, and perhaps migrate the application (with existing data) to a dedicated hosting solution.

This is why I want to know whether it is safe to change the OAuth Domain of an existing application.